# How can i fix this error in my logs file? [session uid=1000 pid=1396] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'

Tags: firefox, 22.10

I'm experiencing many Firefox crashes, and right after that when i check "logs file" i see this `[session uid=1000 pid=1396] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'`

Please tell me what the message means and how to prevent this in the future...

Here is a screenshot of it...

[image]

EDIT: ADDED LOGS

[image]

EDIT 2: i asked this question before if you want to check the reports **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437309/firefox-suddenly-crashes-ubuntu-22-10-error-says-needs-allocation)**

i added a bounty because i really want to fix this because every time Firefox freezes i lose my tabs...

here is report of last time it froze again today!

[image]

Comment: It says it wrote to the logs. What is in the logs?

Comment: @David I added a screenshot of all the logs, thank you so much

Comment: @David i asked this same question yesterday but since no one answered and firefox crashed again for the third time today! i asked the question again... here is the question i asked yesterday if you want to see the logs i took... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437309/firefox-suddenly-crashes-ubuntu-22-10-error-says-needs-allocation

Comment: All asking the same question over and over will get you is both or all of the question removed. You can not expect an immediate answer.

Comment: What does `inxi-G` say? I still assume this is a problem with nvidia and XWayland

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've hit the mp4parse error [described here](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/105195). This could be a problem with your graphics card in conjunction with using wayland.

Log out and switch to XSever (the cogg on the right bottom).

If your tabs contain videos (e.g. youtube) you might try to install a firefox [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/enhanced-h264ify/) that prevents VP8/VP9 codecs.

Comment: Is there a simpler way without logging out, like starting firefox using XWayland?

Comment: No. I proposed this in order to narrow down the problem. Currently firefox is using XWayland, so the goal is to test if it also freezes if you're on XServer. If the hardware runs with a Nivida card (which wasn't mentioned), it could be a problem in with XWayland