# ERROR mp4parse : Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0" error while running Firefox on Ubuntu 22.10 freezes any youtube videos

Tags: firefox, browser, multimedia, mp4, 22.10

I've just upgraded ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10. Everything seems to work great except for Firefox. Infact this is what happens when I run it :

```
ziomario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:~/Scrivania$ firefox

[GFX1-]: More than 2 GPUs detected via PCI, secondary GPU is arbitrary
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
[2022-11-06T16:55:34Z ERROR mp4parse] Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0"
[2022-11-06T16:55:34Z ERROR mp4parse] Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0"
[2022-11-06T16:55:34Z ERROR mp4parse] Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0"
[2022-11-06T16:55:36Z ERROR mp4parse] Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0"
[2022-11-06T18:10:17Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
[2022-11-06T18:10:17Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
[2022-11-06T18:10:17Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
[2022-11-06T18:10:17Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
[2022-11-06T18:10:17Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
```

The problem is that when I try to open any video on youtube,for example,it freezes and I get only an infinite list of the error that you see above (Found 2 nul bytes in "\0\0"). I've tried to look for a solution on the web,but without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i fix this error in my logs file? \[session uid=1000 pid=1396\] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437498/how-can-i-fix-this-error-in-my-logs-file-session-uid-1000-pid-1396-successful)

Comment: I'm using xorg and I've installed the "enhanced-h264ify" addon for firefox,but the problem is still there. I've also upgraded firefox to 106.0.5 version,but this hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official bug report **[1]**
there, you can find more information;

As a side note, I get the same errors on my system but I can play videos without complications;
in fact, I have ever seen it as a simple ***warning***;

---

**[1]** https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1772085